# Make postgres database production on rails 5 for deploy app to heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

My app is not working on heroku but its working properly on my local

My app is deployed successfully on heroku without any error, but when I visit url of my app its showing `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`, and when I check heroku log using `heroku logs -t` its showing error, I dont know whats going wrong, Any suggestion will be appreciated

I am using `MySql` as a database

**UPD: Solve, just need update gem file, because heroku using Postgres databse.**

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'mysql', group: :development
```

Comment: Heroku only support postgres databse, so you have to use postgres databse for production mode.

Comment: You can migrate from mysql to postgress : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails default database is SQL Lite, unless you have changed database.yml this is the database you are using.

Regardless of any configuration changes you make [Heroku only runs on Postgres database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql). You cannot run any other database on Heroku.

If you want to use Mysql in development and PG in production development then you can define group in gemfile like

```
Gemfile
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'mysql', group: :development
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku used postgres database only.

Change Gemfile from

```
gem 'mysql'
```

to

```
gem 'pg'
```